# Validating TextBox input for a list that is a property of an MVC3 ViewModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, client-side-validation, asp.net-mvc-validation

I realize I'm a little late to the party, but... I'm working in my first MVC project, and have been able to get a handle on most of what needs to be done.  Most of the project simply reads data and pumps the data into charts.  However, I have one View whose model looks like this (the parent class properties are not important here):

```
public class Class1 : ParentClass
{
public List<ChildClass> ChildClassList{get;set;}
}
```

and the ChildClass looks like this:

```
public class ChildClass
{
   public int Property1{get;set;}
   public int Property2{get;set;}
   public string Property3{get;set;}

   public int? ID{get;set;}
   [Editable(true)]
   public decimal? Property4{get;set;}
}
```

Now, retreiving the data is not an issue.  I can loop through the list, and create a table for editing like this:

```
<% foreach(var g in Model.ChildClassList){%>
   <tr>
     <td style="text-align: right;">
    <%= Html.Label(g.Property3)%>
 </td>
     <td>
        <%=Html.TextBox(Model.ParentProperty.ToString() + "_" + g.Property2, (g.Property4.HasValue ? g.Property4.Value.ToString("C") : "$0.00"))%>
     </td>
   </tr>
<% }%>
```

After cruising through this site for the past couple of days, it dawned on me that I can validate the input on the server-side, in the POST method (there is a "Save" button at the bottom of the form), but (a)how do I get the validation error message back to the user, (b)perform the validation client-side?.

I must mention also that this view uses the values in the list to create a portion of a chart, prior to being rendered as a table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the server-side in the `[HttpPost]` action, you can check the validity of the model like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(Class1 model)
{
   if (!ModelState.IsValid)
      return View(model);
   // Code to save model.
}
```

You also need to update your View to show the errors:

```
<%= Html.ValidationSummary(false, "Please fix these errors.")
<% foreach(var g in Model.ChildClassList){%>
   <tr>
     <td style="text-align: right;">
    <%= Html.Label(g.Property3)%>
 </td>
     <td>
        <%=Html.TextBox(Model.ParentProperty.ToString() + "_" + g.Property2, (g.Property4.HasValue ? g.Property4.Value.ToString("C") : "$0.00"))%>
        <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => g.Property4)
     </td>
   </tr>
<% }%>
```

If you want to enable it client-side, you need to use **unobstrusive client validation**, which you can do by updating your web.config:

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
        <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Also you need the following JS libraries:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"           type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js"      type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jQuery.Validate/1.7/jQuery.Validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/3.0/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**On a side note**, try and avoid loops to render out your View. It's unnecessary code soup, which can be avoided by the use of editor templates.

Comment: RPM, thanks for the input. I understand how to check the model state.  In this scenario it is always valid, because the validation check is in the POST method, and not on the model itself.  The input is going to the Editable property in in a single item in the List of  ChildClass instances.

Comment: (cont.) As for the loop v. the editor template, I don't need an editor for the entire model, just the child class. and since the child class is part of a list, I'd need a loop anyway

Comment: @AndrewMcFallIII - of course the validity check is in the POST method. That's how MVC model validation works. If you enable client-side validation, the same validation occurs, but client-side. As for your second comment, no, you don't need a loop. You would create an editor template for the child class, then do `<%= Html.EditorFor(model => model.Child)` and it would render out the template for the child N number of times.

Comment: The javascript files were a huge help.  Already had the model annotations done for the client side to work.  @RPM11984,  thanks!